# CppUnit tests always passing with Ctest

Tags: cmake, cppunit, ctest

I'm working on a project using CMake and just integrated some CppUnit tests. I would like to use CTest and thus I used add_test in my CMakeLists.txt files to have the tests executed when typing `make test`.
Yet I observe that, when typing `make test`, it says that all the tests passed even if I make a test with trivial errors. Erroneous tests report these errors when executed manually (e.g. ./my_test) but not when executed using `make test`.

Here is the content of my CMakeLists.txt in the test directory:

```
add_executable(TestDataSpace TestDataSpace.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestDataSpace ${DEP_LIBRARIES} ${CPPUNIT_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(TestVariableManager TestVariableManager.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestVariableManager ${DEP_LIBRARIES} ${CPPUNIT_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(TestLayoutManager TestLayoutManager.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestLayoutManager ${DEP_LIBRARIES} ${CPPUNIT_LIBRARIES})

add_test(NAME "TestDataSpace" COMMAND ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/TestDataSpace)
add_test(NAME "TestVariableManager" COMMAND ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/TestVariableManager)
add_test(NAME "TestLayoutManager" COMMAND ${MY_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/TestLayoutManager)
```

CTest does find the executables, since putting a wrong path for the command makes CMake complain that it doesn't find them.

`make test` outputs the following:

> Running tests... Test project
>
> ```
> Start 1: TestDataSpace 1/3 Test #1: TestDataSpace ....................   Passed    0.01 sec
> Start 2: TestVariableManager 2/3 Test #2: TestVariableManager ..............   Passed    0.02 sec
> Start 3: TestLayoutManager 3/3 Test #3: TestLayoutManager ................   Passed    0.01 sec
> ```
>
> 100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 3

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CppUnit, but I suspect your executables are always returning `0`, even if the test fails.  CTest takes a return of `0` to indicate success.

If you change your return value when the test fails to a non-zero number, you should see the expected output from CTest.

Alternatively, you can modify CTest's behaviour by using [`set_tests_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_tests_properties.html) to set the values of [`PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.html) and/or [`FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.html).  If either of these are set, the return value is ignored.  So for example, you could do:

```
set_tests_properties(
    TestDataSpace
    TestVariableManager
    TestLayoutManager
        PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "TEST PASSED;Pass")
```

As an aside, you can avoid passing the full path to the test executables in your case since they are actual CMake targets defined in the same CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_test(NAME TestDataSpace COMMAND TestDataSpace)
add_test(NAME TestVariableManager COMMAND TestVariableManager)
add_test(NAME TestLayoutManager COMMAND TestLayoutManager)
```

Comment: That does work, however CMake seems to be redirecting the standard outputs from the tests (which, using CppUnit, prints a lot of useful information to indicate where the error was), and only tells if the test passed or not. When a test doesn't pass, I still have to run it again manually to have a better report. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Rather than `make test`, from your build folder you should be able to run `ctest -V` for verbose output, or `ctest --output-on-failure`

Comment: You can also try `make check` as this prints verbose output without need to directly call `ctest`.

Comment: AFAIK `make check` is not available by default